# sql server-conditional where clause

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

Suggest me the proper syntex for below raw condition.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro_name]
@number as int ,

Select * from table 
if(@number=0)
begin
set @number=select max(number)from table
end
where table.number=@number
```

here i need to set @number with max value if input value passed is '0'. and also want to use th e same in wherer clause.

Comment: the `WHERE` clause - do you want `@number` to be used before or after calculating `MAX` ?

Comment: where table.number=
case number
when 0 then MAX(table.number)
else number (NOT WORKING  )

Comment: @YS. i want where clause with conditional value i.e if else before where clause. in any case use number but with diff value (according to the condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro_name]
@number as int=0 --I recommend a default value here too
as
set @number=case @number when 0 then (select max(number)from [table]) else @number end;

Select * from [table] t
where t.number=@number;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Since there is not point in having two exactly the same answers and I was beaten, here is an alternate solution:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[pro_name]
@number as int as

select top 1 * from [table]
where number = @number or @number = 0
order by [table].number desc
```

*However this will only work if the number column is unique, which may or may not be the case in your case.*